# string insert and dereference _problem_

Tags: c++, string, stl

This is easy to do but seemly hard to do correctly. Lets pretend l is size()/2. I want to insert the last half of sz into szout.

My first attempt was

```
szout.insert(szout.end(), &sz[l], sz.end());
```

But I got a big compile error. Next thing I tried was

```
szout.insert(szout.end(), &sz[l], &sz[sz.size()-1]);
```

Nope, missing the last letter. So obviously I shouldn't -1

```
szout.insert(szout.end(), &sz[l], &sz[sz.size()]);
```

This works but this is undefined behavior because I'm deferencing past the last letter.

```
szout.insert(szout.end(), &sz[l], &sz[sz.size()-1]+1);
```

This works but feels wrong. A -1 and +1... thats just weird.

Whats the correct way to copy to the last letter?

Comment: `&sz[l]` is a `char*` but `sz.end()` is a `string::iterator`, they are not the same type. Either use two pointers or two iterators, don't mix them

Comment: Now that's a useless title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This works but this is undefined behavior because I'm deferencing past the last letter.

No, you are not dereferencing past the last letter. You are taking an address of "one character past the last letter", but that is explicitly allowed by the standard.

This language is very common in the C++ standard:

> 24.2.1.5: Just as a regular pointer to an array guarantees that there is a pointer value pointing past the last element of the array, so for any iterator type there is an iterator value that points past the last element of a corresponding sequence.

Essentially, any pointer `P` pointing one past the end of any array is considered valid. Same goes for iterators.

Trying to read or write the `sz[sz.size()]` would indeed be wrong, though, but your code is not doing it: the standard library always interprets the ending pointer as "one past the end", so you are absolutely safe with

```
szout.insert(szout.end(), &sz[l], &sz[sz.size()]);
```

Comment: +1 Wouldn't that just be `(szout.end(), sz.begin()+l, sz.end())`

Comment: @WhozCraig Absolutely, this would work too. I just wanted to point out that "one past the end" is perfectly valid for both pointers and iterators.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. I would +1 this again if I could just for the proper standard reference, which many people fail to grasp if they ever breeze through it. The intention of being able to have a defined pointer/iterator one item past a sequence is pretty core to the language, and I'm honestly surprised how many people don't realize is is actually *defined* in the standard to work that way.